# How to use .then for async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, callback

So I am trying to chain request from an api and I am aware of that this is an asynchronous request. However it is my understanding that using `.then()` returns a promise, and that the code waits for it to be resolved before moving on to the next `.then()`. When I `console.log`the variable `encryptedAccountId` instead of returning it, I get the desired result. But when I try to put that into the next url, it says the variable is undefined. I have also trying using `await` and `async` but to no luck. What am I missing here?

````
let summonerName = 'nightblue3';
const region = ['na1', 'br1', 'eun1', 'euw1', 'jp1', 'kr', 'la1', 'la2', 'oc1', 'ru', 'tr1'];
let endIndex = 100;
let beginIndex = 0;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

  let userUrl = `https://${region[0]}.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key=${apiKey}`
  fetch(userUrl).then(res => {
        return res.json()})
        .then(getEncryptedAcccountId=> {
        var encryptedAccountId = (getEncryptedAcccountId.accountId)
        return encryptedAccountId})
        .then(fetch(`https://${region[0]}.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/${encryptedAccountId}?endIndex=${endIndex}&beginIndex=${beginIndex}&api_key=${apiKey}`))```
````

Comment: `.then(fetch())` should be `then(encryptedAccountId => fetch())`

Comment: @VLAZ You truly are a saint sir. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it easier:

```
fetch(userUrl).then(res => res.json())
   .then(({ accountId }) => fetch(`your_url_with_${accountId}`))
```

Comment: and don't forget the `catch`

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass to `then()` will, indeed, not be called until the promise `then` is called on resolves.

> ```
> .then(fetch(`https://${region[...
> ```

The problem is that you are not passing a function to `then`. You are *immediately* calling `fetch()` and passing its *return value* (which is a promise, not a function).

Pass a function instead:

```
.then((encryptedAccountId) => fetch(`https://${region[...
```

---

You might also like to move to [`async`/`await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) which is generally more readable:

```
(async function () {
  let summonerName = "nightblue3";
  const region = ['na1', 'br1', 'eun1', 'euw1', 'jp1', 'kr', 'la1', 'la2', 'oc1', 'ru', 'tr1'];
  let endIndex = 100;
  let beginIndex = 0;
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");

  let userUrl = `https://${region[0]}.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/${summonerName}?api_key=${apiKey}`;
  const userResponse = await fetch(userUrl);
  const userData = await userResponse.json();
  const encryptedAccountId = userData.accountId;
  const matchlists = await fetch(
    `https://${region[0]}.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/${encryptedAccountId}?endIndex=${endIndex}&beginIndex=${beginIndex}&api_key=${apiKey}`
  );
  // ...
})();
```

Comment: thanks for that, but when i put ```console.log(encryptedAccountId)``` within the async, everything runs, but I can not get visual verification on the variable.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "visual verification on the variable"

Comment: i just want to console.log the data so i can see exactly what I am pulling

Comment: how do i ```console.log( encryptedAccountId)``` to be clear